# Pathfinder.js to Html

Tags: ionic-framework, path-finding

Hello guys I'm trying to implement pathfinder.js to ionic but I dont know how to drow them also in their web page there is no  information about html is there anyone who worked with this liblary(In ionic project there is index.html and other html files like home.html,  but I dont know which html page should have thoose code its complicated for me)

**JS**

```
    var matrix = [
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    ];

    $(function () {
     var Grid = function (width, height) {
      var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
});
var grid = new foo.Grid(matrix);
}
```

I don't know just tried  this code I'm new with these.

Thank you